# Trouble with Spinner: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed

Tags: android, events, spinner

As the title says, I get this error while interacting with a Spinner. I've noticed that there are many post about this argument, but every one is different from each other (answers too). Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution, so I'm asking here.

**Here is a screenshot of the Spinner:**

[image]

As you can see, the first Spinner is ok, but the second has two problems:

- First one, it doesn't show values
- Second one, when I tap the spinner, nothing happen. If I tap again the spinner, I get the error "*Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed*."

Maybe the two things are connected somehow...

**Here is the code:**

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    Integer[] radiusArray = new Integer[]{500,700,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,4000,5000};
    Integer[] geofenceRadius = new Integer[]{100,200,300,400,500};

    try {

        final Spinner spinnerRA = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.search_radius);
        final Spinner spinnerGR = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.geofence_radius);

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapterRA = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, radiusArray);
        spinnerRA.setAdapter(adapterRA);

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapterGR = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, geofenceRadius);
        spinnerRA.setAdapter(adapterGR);

        //Getting from preference files, saved settings, if any
        //1000 and 100 are default settings
        final SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Settings",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String temp = getResources().getString(R.string.search_radius);
        int savedRadius  = sharedPref.getInt(temp, 1000);
        temp = getResources().getString(R.string.geofence_radius);
        int savedGeofence = sharedPref.getInt(temp, 100);

        //Show selected value for spinner, or default value
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<radiusArray.length; i++){
            if(radiusArray[i].equals(savedRadius)){
                break;
            }
        }
        spinnerRA.setSelection(i);

        for(i=0; i<geofenceRadius.length; i++){
            if(geofenceRadius[i].equals(savedGeofence)){
                break;
            }
        }
        spinnerGR.setSelection(i);

        Button Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_settings_button);

        Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Integer searchRadius = (Integer)spinnerRA.getSelectedItem();
                Integer geofenceRadius = (Integer)spinnerGR.getSelectedItem();


                //Saving new value of search_radius
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putInt(getString(R.string.search_radius),searchRadius);
                editor.putInt(getString(R.string.geofence_radius),geofenceRadius);

                editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.initialized),true);
                editor.commit();

                CharSequence text = "Changes saved succesfully!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }


        });

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**And here is the xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textSize="14pt"
        android:layout_marginTop="8pt"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5pt"
        android:id="@+id/second_gray_line"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10pt">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Initial search radius (in meters):"
            android:textColor="#FF8500"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10pt"
            android:layout_marginTop="15pt"
            android:textSize="11pt"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="60pt"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/search_radius"
            android:layout_marginTop="5pt"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5pt">
        </Spinner>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10pt">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Location radius (in meters):"
            android:textColor="#FF8500"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10pt"
            android:layout_marginTop="15pt"
            android:textSize="11pt"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="60pt"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/geofence_radius"
            android:layout_marginTop="5pt"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5pt">
        </Spinner>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/save_settings_button"
        android:text="Save Settings"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50pt"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I think it's a really stupid error, but I can't figure out what causes it. Could you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved and, as I said, the error was really stupid... I made a mistake here, in the second adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapterGR = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, geofenceRadius);
    spinnerRA.setAdapter(adapterGR);
```

This must be changed in:

```
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapterGR = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, geofenceRadius);
    spinnerGR.setAdapter(adapterGR);
```

It was just an oversight. I was setting the second adapter using *spinnerRA* instead of *spinnerGR*. Now it works!